# Is there a different way of implementing this program without using nested while loop?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Presently my program is working properly, but how do i implement this  program without using nested while loop(one while loop within another while loop).This is a kids way of programming and my office colleague doesn't want me to write code like this.So is there a different way for implementing this program or a proper way of implementing the while loops seen in the above code??

This IS MY CURRENT CODE:

```
package Snomed.Snomed;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Date;

import catalog.Root;

public class Snomedinfo {
    public void snomedinfoinsert() {
        Root oRoot = null;
        ResultSet oRsSelect = null;
        PreparedStatement oPrStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement oPrStmt2 = null;
        PreparedStatement oPrStmtSelect = null;
        String strSql = null;

        String snomedcode = null;
        ResultSet oRs = null;
        String refid = null;
        String id = null;
        String effectivetime = null;
        String active = null;
        String moduleid = null;
        String conceptid = null;
        String languagecode = null;
        String typeid = null;
        String term = null;
        String caseSignificanceid = null;

        try {
            oRoot = Root.createDbConnection(null);
            strSql = "SELECT  id FROM snomed_conceptdata WHERE active=1 ";
            oPrStmt2 = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(strSql);
            oRsSelect = oPrStmt2.executeQuery();
            String strSql2 = "SELECT  * FROM snomed_descriptiondata WHERE conceptid =? AND active=1  ";
            oPrStmtSelect = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(strSql2);
            String sql = "INSERT INTO snomedinfo_data (refid,id,effectivetime,active,moduleid,conceptid,languagecode,typeid,term,caseSignificanceid) VALUES( ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            oPrStmt = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(sql);
            while (oRsSelect.next()) //first while loop
            {
                snomedcode = Root.TrimString(oRsSelect.getString("id"));

                oPrStmtSelect.setString(1, snomedcode);

                oRs = oPrStmtSelect.executeQuery();

                while (oRs.next()) //second while loop
                {
                    refid = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("refid"));
                    id = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("id"));
                    effectivetime = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("effectivetime"));
                    active = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("active"));
                    moduleid = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("moduleid"));
                    conceptid = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("conceptid"));
                    languagecode = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("languagecode"));
                    typeid = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("typeid"));
                    term = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("term"));
                    caseSignificanceid = Root.TrimString(oRs.getString("caseSignificanceid"));


                    oPrStmt.setString(1, refid);
                    oPrStmt.setString(2, id);
                    oPrStmt.setString(3, effectivetime);
                    oPrStmt.setString(4, active);
                    oPrStmt.setString(5, moduleid);
                    oPrStmt.setString(6, conceptid);
                    oPrStmt.setString(7, languagecode);
                    oPrStmt.setString(8, typeid);
                    oPrStmt.setString(9, term);
                    oPrStmt.setString(10, caseSignificanceid);
                    oPrStmt.executeUpdate();
                }


            }

            System.out.println("done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            oRsSelect = Root.EcwCloseResultSet(oRsSelect);
            oRs = Root.EcwCloseResultSet(oRs);
            oPrStmt = Root.EcwClosePreparedStatement(oPrStmt);
            oPrStmt = Root.EcwClosePreparedStatement(oPrStmt2);
            oPrStmt = Root.EcwClosePreparedStatement(oPrStmtSelect);
            oRoot = Root.closeDbConnection(null, oRoot);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Snomedinfo a = new Snomedinfo();
        a.snomedinfoinsert();

    }


}
```

NOTE:Also the import process is working but is a little slow.I have already tried using an index for the conceptid column .

Comment: this kind of questions is better asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over again with minor differences. It will only garner you more downvotes and duplicate-close-votes and eventually a question-ban.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Done

Answer (score 1):

Since all data used in the `INSERT` statement comes from your 'SELECT' statements there is no point in taking the extra round-trip between your java app and the database. Executing everything in one SQL statement will give you the best performance.

Your SQL statement should be like this

```
INSERT INTO snomedinfo_data (refid,id,effectivetime,active,moduleid,conceptid,languagecode,typeid,term,caseSignificanceid)
SELECT d.refid, d.id, d.effectivetime, d.active, d.moduleid, d.conceptid, d.languagecode, d.typeid, d.term, d.caseSignificanceid
FROM snomed_descriptiondata d
JOIN snomed_conceptdata c ON c.id = d.conceptid AND c.active = 1 AND d.active = 1
```

And your java code can be boiled down to this

```
try {
    oRoot = Root.createDbConnection(null);
    String sql = "INSERT INTO snomedinfo_data...";
    oPrStmt = oRoot.con.prepareStatement(sql);
    oPrStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: i want the queries to be seperate!! dont want to use a single query or any kind of joins!!

Comment: plus both the tables snomed_descriptiondata and snomed_conceptdata has more than 1300000 rows of data so it will be very slow!!

Comment: No, there is no way a single insert statement can be slower than what you have today. On the contrary, it should be much much faster, when you have so many rows there is nothing that will be faster than the dabase. And not want to use a single query or joins makes no sense.

Comment: so there is no way to avoid the nested while loop without using  single query or joins??

Comment: @davidmathew not what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

If i am reading your code correctly you are reading from one table and adding to another and never use the data in your application. If this is a case then best case scenario is to write a db procedure that will transform your data and execute it from your app.

Answer (score 0):

if I am correct you are using two queries for fetching data from db.
use this nested query, it will save the database connection effort and nested while loop

SELECT * FROM snomed_descriptiondata WHERE conceptid in (SELECT  id FROM snomed_conceptdata WHERE active=1) AND active=1

Comment: i want the queries to be seperate!! dont want to use a single query or any kind of joins!!

Comment: plus both the tables snomed_descriptiondata and snomed_conceptdata has more than 1300000 rows of data so it will be very slow!!

Comment: first get the data from snomed_conceptdata table and store in list. then if you are familiar with multi threading use Executor framework where a worker thread will  read data record from  snomed_descriptiondata table and insert in other table.